# Interact with element in UITableView.backgroundView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which displays some data. If there is no data to display, I show an empty with a button in it. I'm taking advantage of the tableView's backgroundView feature to display my empty state. The problem is that I cannot interact with that button. I assume the tableView disables interaction with the background view. Is there some way to enable it?

Comment: Maybe you should think about why you place a button there. What would you want to do with that button?

Comment: It opens up the search filters so that the user can adjust their criteria

Comment: Maybe instead you could put the button under the table view and hide the table view when it is empty, which would make the button visible.

Answer (score 0):

You should create strong variable to your background view controller.

```
class ExampleController: UIViewController {
   ...

   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

   private let emptyStateVC = EmptyStateVc(nibName: "EmptyStateVc", bundle: nil)

   ...

   private func setupTableView() {
     tableView.backgroundView = emptyStateVC.view
     tableView.backgroundView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   }
}
```